# How to pass a value when a condition is met during a foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script to audit our job scheduling program. When iterating through job steps of a job, if the job has a value of 'Log' I want to set the variable `$LogStatus` to 'Enabled'. So far it prints the correct command, however when the variable is exported to my spread sheet its always 'Disabled'. I believe this is because the script iterates over the next job step and re-writes the value of the variable.

This is a COM API script running against the Active Batch job scheduler. I have tried adding a break and continue into the foreach loop, however the value keeps being overwritten.

```
#Create new Job Scheduler Object and connect to Job Scheduler
$SchedulerObject = New-Object -ComObject "ActiveBatch.AbatJobScheduler"; 
$SchedulerObject.Connect('JOBSERVER');
#$JobObject = $SchedulerObject.GetAbatObject(510621);
$JobObjects = $SchedulerObject.Search("/BackOffice/PROD/FINRA Trace Treasury Report/","*",1,"*",$true);

foreach($Job in $JobObjects)
{
    $i = 1
    $JobObject = $Job.getAbatObject();
    write-host("Job Name: " + $JobObject.Name)  
    write-host ("Job Path: " + $JobObject.Path)
    $MonitoringObjects = $JobObject.RunTimeMonitorProperties.AbortOnTimeOverrun
    $UnderrunObjects = $JobObject.RunTimeMonitorProperties.FailOnTimeUnderrun
    if ($MonitoringObjects -eq $true)
        {
        write-host("Abort On Overrun Enabled")
        $Overrun = "Enabled"
        }
    else 
        {
        write-host("Abort On Overrun Disabled")
        $Overrun = "Disabled"
        }
    if ($UnderrunObjects -eq $true)
        {
        write-host("Fail On Underrun Enabled")
        $Underrun = "Enabled"
        }
    else 
        {
        write-host("Fail on Underrun Disabled")
        $Underrun = "Disabled"
        }
    $JobSteps = $JobObject.Steps;
    foreach ($JobStep in $JobSteps)
        {
        $StepProperties = $JobStep.Value;
        foreach ($StepProperty in $StepProperties)
            {
            #write-host("Step Value: " + $StepProperty.Value)
            #write-host("Step Name: " + $StepProperty.Name)
            if($StepProperty.Value -eq "Log")
                {
                write-host("ActiveBatch records server side logs for this job")
                $LogStatus = "Enabled"
                break
                }
            else
                {
                #write-host("Step Value Not Condition: " + $StepProperty.Value)
                #write-host("Step Name Not Condition: " + $StepProperty.Name)
                $LogStatus = "Disabled"
                }
            }
        }
    $AlertObjects = $JobObject.GetAssociatedAlertObjects()
    foreach ($Alert in $AlertObjects)
        {
        write-host("Name of Associated Alert Object: " + $Alert.Name)
        }
    $DaysOfWeekArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
    $JobConstraints = $JobObject.GetExclusionList()
    foreach ($ExclusionList in $JobConstraints)
        {
        #$Constraint = ("Contraint #" + $i)
        #write-host($Constraint)
        $DaysOfWeek = $ExclusionList.DateTime_DaysOfWeek
        if($DaysOfWeek -ge 64)
            {
            $DaysOfWeek-= 64;
            $DaysOfWeekArray.Add('Saturday') > $null;
            }
        if($DaysOfWeek -ge 32)
            {
            $DaysOfWeek-= 32;
            $DaysOfWeekArray.Add('Friday') > $null;
            }
        if($DaysOfWeek -ge 16)
            {
            $DaysOfWeek-= 16;
            $DaysOfWeekArray.Add('Thursday') > $null;
            }
        if($DaysOfWeek -ge 8)
            {
            $DaysOfWeek-= 8;
            $DaysOfWeekArray.Add('Wednesday') > $null;
            }
        if($DaysOfWeek -ge 4)
            {
            $DaysOfWeek-= 4;
            $DaysOfWeekArray.Add('Tuesday') > $null;
            }
        if($DaysOfWeek -ge 2)
            {
            $DaysOfWeek-= 2;
            $DaysOfWeekArray.add('Monday') > $null;
            }
        if($DaysOfWeek -eq 1)
            {
            $DaysOfWeek-= 1;
            $DaysOfWeekArray.Add('Sunday') > $null;
            }
        write-host("Days of Week: " + $DaysOfWeekArray);
        #$DaysOfWeekArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;    
        }
    write-host("")
    $details = @{
        Job_Name = $JobObject.Name
        Job_Path = $JobObject.Path
        Abort_On_Overrun = $Overrun
        Fail_On_Underrun = $Underrun
        #Constraint = $Constraint
        Days_Contraints = $DaysOfWeekArray
        Server_Side_logging = $LogStatus
        Alert_Object = $Alert.Name
            }
    $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
}
$results | select-object -property Job_Path,Job_Name,Abort_On_Overrun,Fail_On_Underrun,Days_Contraints,Server_Side_Logging,Alert_Object | export-csv -Path "c:\AB Job Contraints.csv" -NoTypeInformation 
$SchedulerObject.Disconnect();

I expect the correct value to be carried to the `$LogStatus` variable that ends up being output. However I will only get an 'Enabled' value if the last step fulfills the requirement.
```

Comment: Looks like your `$details` variable and the `$Results +=` appear to be a little to shallow. Can you try dropping them down into the `$Jobstep` loop and provide the results?

Comment: The line `Job.getAbatObject()` is missing a leading $. Please ensure you have edited your question with the actual code exactly pasted, and then we’ll try again.

Comment: You assign to `$JobObect`, but use `$JobOjbect` (notice the `j`) in the rest of the script

Comment: Script has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I put a label on the outer foreach loop then used a 'break label' when the condition was met.

```
$JobSteps = $JobObject.Steps;
    :Step foreach ($JobStep in $JobSteps)
        {
        $StepProperties = $JobStep.Value;
        foreach ($StepProperty in $StepProperties)
            {
            #write-host("Step Value: " + $StepProperty.Value)
            #write-host("Step Name: " + $StepProperty.Name)
            if($StepProperty.Value -eq "Log")
                {
                write-host("ActiveBatch records server side logs for this job")
                $LogStatus = "Enabled"
                break Step
                }
            else
                {
                #write-host("Step Value Not Condition: " + $StepProperty.Value)
                #write-host("Step Name Not Condition: " + $StepProperty.Name)
                $LogStatus = "Disabled"
                }
            }
        }
```